# How do I check for a Rails session in node-http-proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, node.js, proxy

We have a Rails app with a view that gets populated with data from a third-party API. Currently, this view uses a swf streamer to open a socket to the endpoints.

Recently, the API's provider has asked us to switch to long polling ajax calls, and to pipe requests through a proxy in our server.

We're considering using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), to take advantage of node's speed and concurrency handling in case we get high traffic. We're new to Node.js, though.

The other option we're looking at is using the Rails app itself to forward these requests, the advantage being that we could use the existing session handling.

We'd prefer to use node-http-proxy, as it seems the most elegant solution (and an opportunity to play with Node.js, of course ;), but haven't figured out how to integrate it with our app's sessions (activerecord session store on postgres).

Is there a way to do it? Are there any other auth/security/session-checking strategies using node-http-proxy in parallel with a Rails app?

Oliver